# How to resize image with CSS without altering image quality

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a Bootstrap carousel with the below code; how can I size this image to completely fill the carousel with losing image quality and also ensure the image height does not exceed the width or height of the carousel? [image]

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active" style="width:400px;">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{articles.image.url}}" alt="First slide" style=" width:100%;height:auto;">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>Latest</h5>
        <p>{{articles.title}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src=".../800x400?auto=yes&bg=666&fg=444&text=Second slide" alt="Second slide">{% lorem 1 p %}
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src=".../800x400?auto=yes&bg=555&fg=333&text=Third slide" alt="Third slide">{% lorem 1 p %}
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Could at least provide a working code snippet, Not just copy your code bluntly.

Answer (score 18):

Use object fit property in your css, and give a fixed width and height to 
your image tag or respective class so that every image will have same width and height, Now Your Image won't be distorted.

```
 .d-block w-100 {
   width:100%;
   height:550px;
   object-fit:cover;
   object-position:50% 50%;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make the image 100% width and height auto.

Comment: i have done  this but the height is too much and still goes out hand i just want it to maintain the height of the carousel

Comment: Try reducing the height of the image container by setting max-helght

Answer (score 1):

**Old** code:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active" style="width:400px;">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{articles.image.url}}" alt="First slide" style=" width:100%;height:auto;">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>Latest</h5>
        <p>{{articles.title}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src=".../800x400?auto=yes&bg=666&fg=444&text=Second slide" alt="Second slide">{% lorem 1 p %}
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src=".../800x400?auto=yes&bg=555&fg=333&text=Third slide" alt="Third slide">{% lorem 1 p %}
    </div>
  </div>
```

Edit the `carousel-item` with:

```
width: 100%;
height: auto;
```

Comment: i am doing the what you said but the height still is is not reduce as it extends the carousel height right down

Comment: Hi. You can add the max-height to your carousel if not. Then specify the exact height you want the carousel to be, you can do this in multiple measurements, for example px, em, rem etc.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use css background images instead of img tags and using the background-size cover property, which has more browser support as compared to img object fit property.

```
<div class="carousel-item" style="background: url('')"></div>

.carousel-item{
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #000;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My previous image size was 960px*720px I was using it for a logo. This worked in reducing the size without stretching.

Using a CSS selector to point to that image adjust the height

```
{ height: 100px;}
```

The default value of width is auto.
You could adjust the value of the height as you see fit depending on what you are aiming for.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and I fixed that by add d-flex and justify content to center images like this,

```
<div class="slide-control d-flex justify-content-center">
```

Then I used those CSS property

```
.slide-image {
    width: auto;
    height: 870px; 
   }
   .slide-control{
    margin: 40px 177px 0 177px;
   }
```

You should use margin inside  .slide-control  class , otherwise slide will go,  end of the left side.